# Kubernetes: How to expose a Pod as a service

Tags: kubernetes

I am learning kubernetes and created first pod using below command

```
kubectl run helloworld --image=<image-name> --port=8080
```

The Pod creation was successful.
But since it is neither a ReplicationController or a Deloyment, how could I expose it as a service. Please advise.

Comment: Refer to : https://jamesdefabia.github.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_expose/

Comment: Services (in general) only expose Pods, not Deployments or ReplicationControllers. Create a service with a `selector` that matches the labels on your Pod. See [the docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) for more information on Service objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks All
I was able to achieve using below command (thanks to comment from Amit kumar):

```
# Create a service for a pod valid-pod, which serves on port 444 with the name "frontend"
kubectl expose pod valid-pod --port=444 --name=frontend
```

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to the documentation of **kubernetes service concept** https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/expose/expose-intro/
At the end of the page, there also is an interactive tutorial in minikube

Answer (score 2):

You can create the service with the same set of selector and labels

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: helloworld
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 9376
```

so if selector matching it will route the traffic to POD and you can expose it.

ref : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/

Answer (score 0):

You may simply use --expose while creating the pod

```
$ kubectl run nginx --image=nginx --port=80 --expose
service/nginx created
pod/nginx created
```